# What does the Python .find() string method return?

Tags: python

I was wondering if I could get some help from you about the .find() string method in python. So here is an example:

```
    word = 'banana'
    index = word.find('a')
    1#result
    word.find('na') 
    2#result
    word.find('na', 3)
    4#result 
    name = 'bob' 
    name.find('b', 1, 2) 
    -1#result
```

Could you explain what this string method specifically does? 
Also for the part word.find('na') and word.find('b',1,2), what are the numbers for and what is the meaning of the results that happen when running these commands?? Thank you for helping out!

Comment: The numbers are indices. So in your last example it searches `'bob'[1:2]` for 'b' and doesn't find it (because `'bob'[1:2]` is 'o'): https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: print str.find.__doc__
S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int

Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

Return -1 on failure.
```

google all the words in the doc string you don't understand, and you will have your answer